# Not able to pass context to non activity class?

Tags: android

I'm trying to open SQLite to an extends non activity class.  Is this possible?  DBCustomerReceipt is my DBHelper.  I'm able to access it via my Activity classes no issue, but when I try to an extends non activity class, I get error "DBCustomerReceipt (android.content.Context) in DBCustomerReceipt cannot be applied."  Here are my code below.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
public class EnglishReceiptsImpl extends ILocalizeReceipts {
//public class EnglishReceiptsImpl extends Activity {

    public EnglishReceiptsImpl() {
        mLanguageCode = "En";

        mCharacterCode = CharacterCode.Standard;
    }

    public void append2inchTextReceiptData(ICommandBuilder builder, boolean utf8) {
        Charset encoding;

        DBCustomerReceipt cCR = new DBCustomerReceipt(**this**);
        cCR.open();

}
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. Be sure to include all relevant declarations. Whic line causes the error?

Comment: Also note the line which you commented out.

Comment: is `EnglishReceiptsImpl` will work from an Activity?

Comment: Can you post your `ILocalizeReceipts` code?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `EnglishReceiptsImpl` does not extend `Context`. You commented out the line that would make this possible:

```
//public class EnglishReceiptsImpl extends Activity {
```

if you returns this line then you can fix the current error. However, you won't be able to also extend `ILocalizeReceipts`. If you need to do so, then you will have to modify the constructor to take a `Context` and pass it in wherever you instantiate `EnglishReceiptsImpl`.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  if I extends to Activity the line that I commented, it will work.  I need to extend to ILocalizeReceipts.  How would I modify the constructor to pass Context to EnglishReceipsImpl?  Thanks!

Comment: @TimDiep You modify the constructor in exactly the same way as `DBCustomerReceipt`'s constructor.